# How to apply a texture to a geodesic sphere in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, texture-mapping, uv-mapping, geodesic-sphere

When I apply a texture to a non-geodesic sphere the sphere has one look, but when `SCNSphere.isGeodesic` is set to `true`, the sphere has an absolutely different look (i.e. not a rotation of the first look).

As I understand the API expects a texture in a different UV mapping. Any ideas? Nothing on the topic in the documentation.

Comment: Indeed, it seems there is no documentation about the UV Layout of a Geodesic SCNSphere. To figure that out, you could probably export such a Sphere to an .obj or whatever format. Then open that geometry in an external Program (like Blender) to see the UV Layout used for the Geodesic (Icosphere) Object.

Comment: @ZAY yup, needs research